# Get a address_components

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using google places API with geocoding. I have a problem with address components type.

I want to get information about address which user typed in autocomplete in this format:
Street number/ street / City/ Province/ Country.

If user autocompleted "Street 12, SomeCity, SomeProvince, SomeCountry", I want to return in alert all of this information. But when user type only "someProvince, SomeCountry", I want to have only province and country address type.

Here is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    alert('0: ' + place.address_components[0].long_name);
    alert('1: ' + place.address_components[1].long_name);
    alert('2: ' + place.address_components[2].long_name);
    alert('3: ' + place.address_components[3].long_name);
    alert('4: ' + place.address_components[4].long_name);
    alert('5: ' + place.address_components[5].long_name);
    alert('6: ' + place.address_components[6].long_name);
    alert('7: ' + place.address_components[7].long_name);
)};
```

Problem is that when user autocomplete full address, it show properly all of this alerts. But when autocomplete only part of information - only country - it will show 7 times what country is typed.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/autocomplete-addressform.html

I want to have, that when street and city is not given, it will show alert ("street is null" etc). How to do it?

Answer (score 14):

Made this function for a project. It parses

- street
- number
- country
- zip
- city

from a google georesponse

```
function parseGoogleResponse(components) {
    _.each(components, function(component) {
      _.each(component.types, function(type) {
        if (type === 'route') {
          $("input[name=street]").val(component.long_name)
        }
        if (type === 'street_number') {
          $("input[name=nr]").val(component.long_name)
        }
        if (type === 'locality') {
          $("input[name=city]").val(component.long_name)
        }
        if (type === 'country') {
          $("input[name=country]").val(component.long_name)
        }
        if (type === 'postal_code') {
          $("input[name=zip]").val(component.long_name)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: This was useful, thanks! Might add that, if using jQuery, the `$.each` needs both an `index` and a `component` passed into its callback function.

Answer (score 14):

[Address Types and Address Component Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types)

Use the types and map them to your address fields. Keep in mind that cities, counties, states etc. can have different meanings depending on their context. For example, `North Hollywood` comes up with type `neighborhood` since it is located in Los Angeles('locality').

```
function placeToAddress(place){
        var address = {};
        place.address_components.forEach(function(c) {
            switch(c.types[0]){
                case 'street_number':
                    address.StreetNumber = c;
                    break;
                case 'route':
                    address.StreetName = c;
                    break;
                case 'neighborhood': case 'locality':    // North Hollywood or Los Angeles?
                    address.City = c;
                    break;
                case 'administrative_area_level_1':     //  Note some countries don't have states
                    address.State = c;
                    break;
                case 'postal_code':
                    address.Zip = c;
                    break;
                case 'country':
                    address.Country = c;
                    break;
                /*
                *   . . . 
                */
            }
        });

        return address;
    }
```

Comment: I'd just like to say thanks very much for your solution which has provided a basis for a robust way to interrogate the address information returned by Google.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 6):

As per the [demo](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/autocomplete-addressform.html), you need to check each of the returned address components to see if a street / city has been returned:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var components = place.address_components;
    var street = null;
    for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
        console.log(component);
        if (component.types[0] == 'route') {
            street = component['long_name'];
        }
    }
    alert('Street: ' + street);
});
```

Comment: Demo doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

Made this function for AngularJS:

```
function getAddressComponentByPlace(place) {
    var components;

    components = {};

    angular.forEach(place.address_components, function(address_component) {
        angular.forEach(address_component.types, function(type) {
            components[type] = address_component.long_name;
        });
    });

    return components;
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
administrative_area_level_1: "Berlin"
country: "Deutschland"
locality: "Berlin"
political: "Deutschland"
postal_code: "10719"
route: "Kurfürstendamm"
street_number: "1"
sublocality: "Bezirk Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf"
sublocality_level_1: "Bezirk Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf"
```

### ES6 Version

```
  const parseGoogleAddressComponents = (addressComponents) => {
    let components = {};
    addressComponents.forEach((addressComponent) => {
      addressComponent.types.forEach((type) => {
        components[type] = addressComponent.long_name;
      });
    });
  
    return components;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function in pure Javascript to get the corresponding type from a `google.maps.GeocoderAddressComponent` object

```
//gets "street_number", "route", "locality", "country", "postal_code"
function getAddressComponents(components, type) {    

    for (var key in components) {
        if (components.hasOwnProperty(key)) {            

            if (type == components[key].types[0]) {
                return components[key].long_name;
            }  
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple suggestion:

```
function parseGoogleResponse (components) {
  var newComponents = {}, type;
  $.each(components, function(i, component) {
    type = component.types[0];
    newComponents[type] = {
      long_name: component.long_name,
      short_name: component.short_name
    }
  });
  return newComponents;
}
```

And the usage will be:

`var components = parseGoogleResponse( places[0].address_components );`

Answer (score 1):

Simple ES6 version:

`const addComponents = gPlaceObj?.place?.address_components`

And then select each component you want using a `filter`:

`const country = addComponents.filter(x => x?.types?.includes('country'))[0];`

Which would give you this `console.log(country)`:

`{"long_name": "United States", "short_name": "US", "types": ["country", "political"]}`