# How to display google place autocomplete data to textbox

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api

I am implementing Google Place Autocomplete for my project but I am not good with Google codes so I am hoping someone help me.

Now what I am trying with Google Place Autocomplete is storing searched value to text box and which is:

1. Street address 1
2. Street address 2
3. City
4. State
5. Zip code
6. Country
7. Latitude
8. Longitude

**Here is my very basic code:**

**JS Part:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    window.onload = function() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var options = {
            componentRestrictions : {
                country : 'de' // What to pass here, If I want to allow search result from all country?
            }
        };

        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }//]]>

</script>
```

**HTML Part:**

```
<label for="searchTextField">Google Place Autocomplete:</label>
<br>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
<br><br>
<div>
    <label for="ad1">Street address 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="ad1" id="ad1" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="ad2">Street address 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="ad2" id="ad2" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="state">State</label>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="zcode">Zip code</label>
    <input type="text" name="zcode" id="zcode" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lat">Latitude</label>
    <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="long">Longitude</label>
    <input type="text" name="long" id="long" value="" />
</div>
```

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDPHm/258/

**Note: I want to allow search from all country.**

I really thankful If someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the code to obatin the address_components such as this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var components = place.address_components;
    var street = null;
    for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
        console.log(component);
        if (component.types[0] == 'route') {
            street = component['long_name'];
        }
    }
    alert('Street: ' + street);
});
```

See this link for more details: [Get a address_components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551593/get-a-address-components)

Hope that helps.  :)

P.S.  Please clarify if the autocomplete is to provide  results from all countries or a certain country.